# ublox GPS strange characters interspersed with NMEA output

Tags: gps, nmea

I am using a ublox GPS for a data acquisition application. The device is outputting NMEA on a virtual COM port.

The NMEA output works just fine. But between the NMEA messages strange characters are interspersed. See screenshot below from Realterm with setting "Ascii".

[image: Realterm screenshot]

Can somebody tell me what this is? And ideally what commands I would need to send to the device to disable this output?

Comment: Two devices using the unit at once by chance?  Maybe it's getting switched back and forth between binary and NMEA?  (Or, does its binary protocol embed NMEA maybe?)

Comment: @Brad What do you mean by "Two devices using the unit at once by chance?" The ublox device I am using is not in an embedded microcontroller application but it is in the form of a USB dongle connected to a PC. Does this answer your question?

Comment: @Brad It is probably some binary but it is definitely not binary emedded in NMEA. Otherwise the binary would be framed by $ and end with *XX\cr\lf. That is not the case here.

Comment: I meant, the other way around.  I know those units have a binary protocol... I wasn't sure if that protocol would embed the NMEA formatted version within.  Sorry I can't be of more specific help... I haven't messed with the binary protocol on these yet, only NMEA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should disable the UBX binary protocol. The NMEA and UBX messages are interleaved on the same port. This can be done by sending UBX-CFG-PRT message disabling the UBX output protocol on your port. You can use the handy u-center application avaiable from u-blox [website](https://www.u-blox.com/en/product/u-center) to perfrom this task.
An alternative is to reflash the device or remove the backup battery. It should default back to NMEA only.