# ublox GPS strange characters in NMEA output

Tags: gps, nmea

I'm having similar difficulties to the gentleman in this post:

[ublox GPS strange characters interspersed with NMEA output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55831738/ublox-gps-strange-characters-interspersed-with-nmea-output)

I am using u-blox on a Dell Rugged 7212 tablet to output NMEA to a virtual com port. I am getting GPS coordinates but I'm also getting a strange line of characters in the middle of the output. Any ideas on what could be causing this?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKOAb.jpg

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ublox GPS strange characters interspersed with NMEA output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55831738/ublox-gps-strange-characters-interspersed-with-nmea-output)

Comment: This is already answered in the question you linked to.  Turn off the binary protocol if you only want NMEA.

Comment: Hi Brad, thanks for the response. I've tried turning off the UBX Binary (at least as far as I can tell) per that above post but I'm still getting that line of code. I think it's maybe something similar going on though but I just can't figure out what setting it is. I'm using the latest version of the U-Blox software if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can try replacing the installed driver with the u-blox VCP device driver for Windows [Download from here](https://www.u-blox.com/en/product-resources/property_file_product_filter/14432). Driver binaries are at the bottom of the page.

This driver creates 2 VCP Virtual COM Ports and publishes the NMEA strings. Beware, this VCP driver does not emulate/work as a Hardware Serialport. So the asynchronous callbacks etc. do not work. You need to busy poll to read the port. After installation of the driver, you can test the driver using Putty or an application like VisualGps to make sure the driver is working the way you expect it to work.